# Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called 'evaluate'

Tags: r, knitr, markup, r-markdown

While adding code chuncks to my .rmd file a la:

````
```{r} %code chunck

```
````

it can't be compiled anymore, and i get a `loadnamespace(name)` error:

```
Error in loadNamespace(name) : 
there is no package called 'evaluate' calls:<Anonymous> ... tryCatch-> Trycatchlist->trycatchoone
```

Has anyone ever experienced it? And how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try `install.packages("evaluate")` and then reattempt compilation. It was probably uninstalled unintentionally at some point.

Answer (score 4):

if it is not installed after tying `install.packages('evaluate')`then,press **ctrl + shift + f10** on RStudio console so this command will restart R session and then try to use `install.packages('evaluate')` command on RStudio console.

Comment: Please edit your question and include explanation of the ctrl + shift + f10 and how it changes the `install.packages...` command

Comment: actually,it restart r session.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the solution was just to install the hexbin package: `install.packages("hexbin")`

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new R session and installing the package again worked for me.